# Что тестируется в этом методе? Espresso

Tags: android, espresso

Читаю документацию по тестам и не пойму на что тестируют UI... 
На то чтоб текст вводился? или чтоб кнопки нажимались? Я просто не могу представить, что я создал допустим кнопку в активити и она не нажимается... В таком случае это проблема гугла, кнопка всегда нажимается.

Ну вот есть пример применения `Espresso`

```
public void testChangeText_sameActivity() {
// Type text and then press the button.
onView(withId(R.id.editTextUserInput))
        .perform(typeText(STRING_TO_BE_TYPED), closeSoftKeyboard());
onView(withId(R.id.changeTextButton)).perform(click());

// Check that the text was changed.
...
}
```

И вот не совсем ясно что должно произойти, чтоб текст не установился. Как по мне самая вероятная причина по которой может что то пойти не так это есть ошибка в самой логике кода. Когда ты расчитываешь, что вернется стринг из метода и его установить в текстовое поле. Если текст не вернется то ничего и не установиться, но это ошибка кода а не UI

Что тестируется в UI?

Answer (score 0):

В данном отрывке кода как я понимаю тестируется:

Во-первых наличие элемента с данным id, в который Вы вводите определенный текст, после чего закрывается клавиаутуру, после чего находите другой элемент с другим id и нажимаете по нему.

Уже после Вы можете дополнительно проверить поменялся ли текст в том месте где Вы его собственно ожидаете.